# What type should I use for a python list for pgloader with postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04, pgloader

My database looks like this:

```
id standard_name organism pmid category_code sub_category_code members_ezid
0 AAANWWTGC_UNKNOWN Homo sapiens 15735639 C3 TFT ["4208", "481"]
```

And then I want to execute the following file by `pgloader csv.load` to load the database in a PostgreSQL table:

```
LOAD CSV
     FROM 'geneset.csv' (a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
     INTO postgresql:///pgloader?csv (a,b,c,d,e,f,g)

     WITH truncate,
          skip header = 1,
          fields optionally enclosed by ' ',
          fields escaped by double-quote,
          fields terminated by '\t'

      SET client_encoding to 'latin1',
          work_mem to '80MB',
          standard_conforming_strings to 'on'

   BEFORE LOAD DO
    $$ drop table if exists csv; $$,
    $$ create table csv (
        a text,
        b text,
        c text,
        d text,
        e text,
        f text,
        g text
       );
  $$;
```

But I get the error:

```
2018-08-29T19:46:52.242000Z ERROR we are reading non quoted csv data and found a quote at 24
```

What type should I use instead of `text` for the entry g?